# If url is /store/*

Tags: php, if-statement

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/store/') {
Echo 'YES!';
}
?>
```

What I want it to do is echo YES! If the url is /store/hfbfifigkrigkg or if its /store/hellosister
So I need something like the * who is used in other languanges as EVERYTHING

THANKS

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
if( preg_match("(^/store/)",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) echo "Yes!";
```

Comment: Almost, shame you forget to escape the directory delimiters : "/^\/store\//"

Comment: @symcbean Erm... why would I need to do that? Slashes are not delimiters in my code!

Comment: Whoops, sorry, yes this works. I guess I need to spend some time thing about why.

Comment: @symcbean Just [read the docs](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) ;)

Answer (score 1):

try with [strpos()](https://www.php.net/strpos) and other many functions you can match like OP answers

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/store/') !== false) {
 echo 'YES!';
}
```

Comment: That should surely by `if (0===strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/store/'))` to avoid matching /something/store/

Comment: @symcbean thanks :) trying to give answer according to question but any wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'store')) {
    echo 'You are now on the store page.';
}
```